# How can I debug exception in eval code in metro style app

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing a Metro Style App in Visual Studio Express 2012 RC, my app works for a while, like 2-3 minutes and then suddenly it says

> Unhandled exception at line 49, column 1343 in eval code
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

and stops working and I don't know why. Here is the part of the eval code which causes the error:

```
var p=function(a){p.queue[bb]()(a)}
```

and it shows

```
p.queue[bb]()(a)
```

as highlighted.

I know its hard to solve this problem by looking at this code, so how can I debug the eval code? It's dynamically created and cannot be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Visual Studio to break as soon as the exception is thrown, that will likely help you debug it.

Debug Menu/Exceptions.../Check the box in both columns for JavaScript

Comment: Sure, but now you can look at the stack better, and understand the state of the app at that time so you can fix it. Looking at your code, bob is indexing into an array, and returning undefined. Wheely try's to invoke that as a function it fails. You need to work out what bb is, and what it's expected to index into